# What can I do to optimize speed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, optimization, django-views

There are 5400 rows of data in the database and it takes too long to calculate them.

In order to increase the calculation speed, I saved all possible combinations according to the filters in the database and I want to calculate on them. This function I wrote does not work fast enough and responds very late.

I give random numbers with the random library but there will be real calculations.
Example: score and history

How can I make this calculation faster?

Django==1.11

Python==3.5

Database: PostgreSQL

[image]

```
from random import randint
def ees_calculate(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
            survey=request.POST['survey']
            language=request.POST['language']
            organization=request.POST['organization']
            year=request.POST['year']
            answer=request.POST['answer']
            table=request.POST['table']

            filters = {
                'organization_filter': organization,
                'survey_filter': survey,
                'language_filter': language,
                'year_filter': year,
                'answer_filter': answer,
                'table_filter': table
            }
        
            ees_combinations = models.Combination.objects.filter(**filters).values('id', 'demographic', 'gender', 'division', 'tenure', 'career_type_level')

            for combination in ees_combinations:
                dev0 = 0
                avg_history = 0
                answer_count = 0
                answer_history_count = 0

                combination_filter = {
                    'age_group': combination['demographic'],
                    'gender': combination['gender'],
                    'division': combination['division'],
                    'tenure': combination['tenure'],
                    'career_type': combination['career_type_level'],
                    'organization_filter': organization,
                    'survey_filter': survey,
                }

                filtered_answers = models.Answer.objects.filter(year_filter=year, **combination_filter).values('score')
                filtered_answer_history = models.Answer.objects.filter(year_filter__lt=year, **combination_filter).values('score')

                answer_count = len(filtered_answers)
                answer_history_count = len(filtered_answer_history)

                if answer_count > 0:
                    avg_score = int(sum(answer['score'] for answer in filtered_answers ) / answer_count)
                
                if answer_history_count > 0:
                    avg_history = int(sum(answer['score'] for answer in filtered_answer_history ) / answer_history_count)
            
                dev0 = int(avg_history / avg_score) if avg_history > 0 and avg_score > 0 else 0

                calculated_data = {
                        'score': randint(1, 100),
                        'history': randint(1, 100),
                        'country_benchmark': randint(1, 100),
                        'industry_benchmark': randint(1, 100),
                        'hp_benchmark': randint(1, 100),
                        'dev0': randint(1, 100), 'dev1': randint(1, 100),
                        'dev2': randint(1, 100), 'dev3': randint(1, 100),

                        's_respondent_count': randint(5, 30),
                        'h_respondent_count': randint(5, 30),
                        'cb_respondent_count': randint(5, 30),
                       'ib_respondent_count': randint(5, 30),
                       'hp_respondent_count': randint(5, 30),
                    }
            
     
                    models.Combination.objects.filter(pk=combination['id']).update(**calculated_data)
                
        response = {'result':'success'}

        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
    else:
        return PermissionError
else:
    return Http404
```

Comment: which database is it?

Comment: @NikhilS PostgreSQL

Comment: Have enough index in table with your filter params?

Comment: use this instead `models.Combination.objects.filter(**filters)`

Comment: @TanThien No, I did not use index

Comment: @sohretaga use index for query is one of the ways help to improve speed

Answer (score 0):

*too long for comment*

Notes:

- you're using very old Django version; some ORM issues may be fixed by moving to a newer version
- this is not a good approach to make long computations within request-response dialog; it's better to involve [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) and run heavy tasks asynchronously
- consider rewriting *ladder of if-elses* into if-return, if-return and then the main block; no effect in code performance but much easier to read
- please use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) for better understanging what is a real bottleneck; there might be other queries executed on a particular page or the number of queries executed might surprise you

Here

```
filtered_answers = models.Answer.objects.filter(year_filter=year, **combination_filter).values('score')
filtered_answer_history = models.Answer.objects.filter(year_filter__lt=year, **combination_filter).values('score')

answer_count = len(filtered_answers)
answer_history_count = len(filtered_answer_history)

if answer_count > 0:
    avg_score = int(sum(answer['score'] for answer in filtered_answers ) / answer_count)

if answer_history_count > 0:
    avg_history = int(sum(answer['score'] for answer in filtered_answer_history ) / answer_history_count)
```

Sum of score and count of rows *must* be counted inside the query with [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations). There is absolutely no need in returning original rows. Also you might prefer to scan `Answers` once to get values for all the years and `group by` attribute "is it current year" or "is it history". Even this `avg_history / avg_score` can be computed on DB side.

Moreover, the result of `Answer` computations - `dev0` is never used. There is a mistake in `calculated_data` initialization or all the code related to `Answers` can be thrown away.

If the only thing you want to do in this metod is resetting values in `Combination` by random integers then you can do this by [bulk update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/optimization/#update-in-bulk) whithout for-loop at all.

Also you might prefer to bulk-delete and [bulk-insert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) in the end of computations instead of updating every row.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing too long for comment, not directly an answer.

What (if any) is the upper bound on the number of rows?

If it's, say, 10000, you may have the option of pulling all relevant data into memory and rummaging through it there. If it's a read-only operation, this can be a winner -- until you run out of memory, so count the rows retrieved to check that this optimization isn't based on a false premise, and log the impending problem before your number of rows grows to completely unmanageable, which you are assuming will be never.

If it's a million, you don't, because you might need several Gb of memory.

Here, you are also updating. I don't have time to follow in detail what  and how, but there is a `bulk_update()` method to avoid N writes of single objects where you have a batch of updated objects all available at once.

And DO update your Django. I've never yet found it hard, just tedious editing of things with their replacements and running all the tests to make sure you didn't break anything.. There are security weaknesses that are fixed only in Django 2, 3 or 4. Your target should be getting to 4.2. (and 5.something once Django 6 arrives).

Django-Debug-toolbar seconded to show the SQL queries. I've been very surprised sometimes by what is *really* slowing things down compared to what I just imagined.